# Failing to open a file which should be in the base path

Tags: go, bazel

I have a Go project (bazel-remote) that tries to read a YAML file passed in the command line, when built with Bazel. This YAML file sits in the same location from where I run the `bazel run` command.

But it fails to run because `os.Open` fails with `_no such file or directory_`.

I printed the `basePath` using `os.Getwd`, because someone suggested that my `basePath` might be set wrong. But my `basePath` is set to a location in my `/private/var/tmp/` where the Bazel objects are created and stored:

```
/private/var/tmp/_bazel`_`<username>``/312feba8ddcde6737ae7dd7ef9bc2a5a/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/darwin_amd64_static_pure_stripped/bazel-remote.runfiles/__main`__
```

How do I set my `basePath` correctly? Why is my `basePath` set to where it is?

Comment: Well, clearly the program is trying to open a file that doesn't exist. Without seeing the code you're using, it's pretty impossible to debug beyond that, though.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the yaml file in the `data` attribute of the `bazel run` target?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jin, add the test.yaml file a data dependency on the binary resolved this issue.

Comment: Jin if you would like to post your comment again as the answer that would be helpful for others. Thanks, Rijo

Comment: Looks like Jay wrote a far more detailed answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binaries started with `bazel run` are executed in an internal Bazel directory. They'll have access to "runfiles", which are files mentioned in the `data` attribute of the binary rule or its dependencies. For example, if you have a rule like the one below, you'll be able to read `foo.txt`, but not `bar.txt` or other files:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary")

go_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hello.go"],
    data = ["foo.txt"],
)
```

Note that the working directory of the binary corresponds to the repository root directory, not the directory where the binary is defined. You can debug with `os.Getwd` and `filepath.Walk`.

You mentioned you wanted to access a yaml file passed in on the command line though. Presumably, you want to be able to access any file the user passes in, not just files mentioned in the `data` attribute. For this case, take a look at the `BUILD_WORKING_DIRECTORY` environment variable (`bazel run` sets this). That gives the path to the directory where `bazel run` was invoked. Also, `BUILD_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY` is the path to the workspace root directory.